# How to convert RDD[Result] to RDD[Row] in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

In our application, we are connecting spark with HBase, using the following code:

```
val hBaseRDD: RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)] = 
sparkSession.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
      conf,
      classOf[TableInputFormat],
      classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[Result]
    )

val resultRDD: RDD[Result] = hBaseRDD.map(tuple => tuple._2)
```

But this provides us with an RDD of type Result.

We need RDD of type 'Row' to create DataFrame out of this RDD.
How can we do the same?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) can help - it is an **Spark** connector that allows you to read data from HBase as a `DataFrame`. Also, I would like to suggest a work around I made for a school project, I created a [**Hive** _external table_](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration) which was really stored in **HBase** and then I _query_ the table from **Spark** using `spark.sql("SELECT colum_name1, ..., colum_name2 FROM hive_hbase_table")` -  but maybe it introduces some overhead...

Comment: you can just extract the fields you want to use out of `Result` and map every `Result` to `Row(firstField, secondField, ...)`!